# Is there an electric-indent for single-line statements in braced languages?

Tags: indentation

My code style for braced languages like C/C++/Java is to use no braces when the statement is a single line. One of my biggest pet peeves is that every IDE I've ever used will not smartly un-indent after this single statement if there is no brace.

I tend to use three spaces for my personal style with some other styles using more. I hate having to tap on the backspace key so many times when I do this.

Has anyone seen anything like this for emacs?

I already use a custom indentation function which I hope can be expanded to include this feature:

```
(defvar my-indentation-width 3
  "The number of spaces I prefer for line indentation.")

(defun my-enter ()
   "Inserts a newline and indents to align with previous line"
   (interactive)
   (newline)
   (unless (looking-back "\\`\n*")
      (indent-relative-maybe)))

(defun my-indentation-setup ()
  "Binds RETURN to the function 'my-enter'"
  (local-set-key "\r" 'my-enter)

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'my-indentation-setup)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-indentation-setup)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-indentation-setup)
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'my-indentation-setup)
```